# More than one thing that needs to be true in if statement for it to execute? c++

Tags: c++

If I want to make a if statement that requires more than one thing to be true do I need to do it with "else if"? Because I think it looks ugly so I would prefer if I could solve that in one statement.

Here is the code:

```
if(x == 2 OR 4 OR 6 OR 8 OR 10)
{
    something......
}

  etc. etc. 
return 0;
```

Will that work?

Comment: your question does not make sense - the OR operator implies that any one of the conditions hold, if you want all conditions to hold then it's AND - so which is it?

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson2.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (x == 2 || x == 4 || x == 6 || x == 8 || x == 10)
{
    ...
}
```

OTOH, if your intent is, "If x is even...":

```
if (x % 2 == 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was actually my intentions :)

Answer (score 4):

There isn't much of a better option than this:

```
if (x == 2 || x == 4 || x == 6 || x == 8 || x == 10)
```

If you wanted to optimize at the cost of readability:

```
if (x > 0 && x <= 10 && (x % 2 == 0))
```

The `%` will be optimized into a bit-wise AND by the compiler.

Comment: Never mind the dude under you had answer. :-) 
Thanks 
Regards.

Comment: Just `if (x % 2 == 0)` will do.